# if $a_k$ is a sequence such that $a_1$ = 1 and $a_{m+n} = a_m + a_n + mn$, What is the value of $a_{12}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let ${a_k}$be a sequence of integters such that $a_1$ = 1 and $a_{m+n} = a_m + a_n + mn$ for all positive integers m and n. What is the value of $a_{12}$ ?

I wasn't sure on how to approach this problem because I am not given $a_2$ so then I wasn't sure how to predict what $a_{m+n}$ would be

Apologies for the lack of thought process for I am new to sequences and series

Comment: To get $a_2$, just set $m=n=1$ (Result is $a_2=3$)

Answer (score 1):

With $b_n=a_n-n^2/2$, we get $b_{m+n}=b_m+b_n$, so by induction $b_n=n\,b_1$. This gives $a_n=n\,(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note: $a_{2n}=a_{n+n}=a_n+a_n+n^2=2a_n+n^2$

$a_{2\cdot1}=2a_1+1=3.$

$a_{2\cdot2}=2a_2+2^2=10.$

$a_{2\cdot4}=2a_4+4^2=36.$

$a_{4+8}=a_4+a_8+4\cdot8=10+36+32=78.$

Comment: How does these remarks lead to the value of $a_{12}$?

Comment: @Did, thank you, I added more details, is it ok now?

Answer (score 0):

We know $a_2 = a_{1+1} = 2 a_1 + 1 = 3$ and $a_3 = a_{2+1} = a_2+a_1 + 2 = 3+1+2 = 6$

$$a_{12} = a_{6+6} = a_{6}+a_{6}+36$$
$$ = 2 a_6 + 36 = 2a_{3+3}+36$$
$$ = 2(2 a_3 + 9) + 36$$
$$ = 2(2  \times 6+9)+36 = 78$$

Answer (score 0):

We can set $m=1$ to get a recursion in $n$ only

$$a_{n+1}=a_n+n+1;$$

If the difference $a_{n+1}-a_n$ is the first order polynomial $n+1$, then $a_n$ will be a second order polynomial, say $a_n=c_2n^2+c_1n+c_0$. Let us compute the difference $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$

$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}-a_{n}&=c_2(n+1)^2+c_1(n+1)+c_0-c_2n^2-c_1n-c_0\\
&=2c_2n+c_2+c_1\\
&=n+1\\
\end{align}$$

and identify coefficients of the same order
$$2c_2=1$$
$$c_2+c_1=1$$

to obtain
$c_1=c_2=\frac{1}{2}$

The remaining $c_0$ may be found from the initial condition
$$a_1=1$$

$$a_1=c_2(1)^2+c_1·1+c_0=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+c_0=1$$

so

$$c_0=0$$

This gives
$$a_n=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

as in Professor Vector's answer (with a longer method here).

For $n=12$ this is

$$a_{12}=\frac{12(12+1)}{2}=78$$